# Supervisord adding multiple processes for PHP and Gearman

Tags: php, gearman, supervisord

I recently set up Ubuntu Natty with PHP5-FPM, Gearman, and Supervisor. I've edited my Supervisord config to run a Gearman worker.

```
[program:gearman] 
command=/usr/bin/php php_gearman_worker.php
numprocs=1 
directory=/root/sandbox
stdout_logfile=/root/sandbox/supervisord.log 
environment=GEARMAN_USER=gearman 
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=gearman
```

Here's the relevant info (showing only gearmand and php processes) when I `lsof -i -P` before I run supervisord:

```
COMMAND     PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
gearmand  29314  gearman    6u  IPv4 328139      0t0  TCP localhost:4730 (LISTEN)
```

And here's what I get when I `lsof -i -P` after I `/etc/init.d/supervisor stop && /etc/init.d/supervisor start`.

```
COMMAND     PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
gearmand  29314  gearman    6u  IPv4 328139      0t0  TCP localhost:4730 (LISTEN)
gearmand  29314  gearman   11u  IPv4 328206      0t0  TCP localhost:4730->localhost:39072 (ESTABLISHED)
php       29571  gearman    4u  IPv4 329744      0t0  TCP localhost:39072->localhost:4730 (ESTABLISHED)
```

I don't see any listing for supervisord itself, should I see supervisord as one the commands?!

Anyway, when I stop and start (or restart) supervisord again:

```
COMMAND     PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
gearmand  29314  gearman    6u  IPv4 328139      0t0  TCP localhost:4730 (LISTEN)
gearmand  29314  gearman   11u  IPv4 328206      0t0  TCP localhost:4730->localhost:39072 (ESTABLISHED)
gearmand  29314  gearman   12u  IPv4 329754      0t0  TCP localhost:4730->localhost:51570 (ESTABLISHED)
php       29571  gearman    4u  IPv4 329744      0t0  TCP localhost:39072->localhost:4730 (ESTABLISHED)
php       29619  gearman    4u  IPv4 327233      0t0  TCP localhost:51570->localhost:4730 (ESTABLISHED)
```

It looks like with each time I stop and start supervisord, it creates another php process, and then another. It's only when I restart gearmand that it goes back to normal i.e. `/etc/init.d/gearman-job-server stop && /etc/init.d/gearman-job-server start`.

This seems abnormal to me being that when I stop supervisord, it's supposed to stop

Is this the way supervisord works?! Is there a way I can prevent this from happening?!

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I found out what was causing the problem. It was a small conflict with the supervisord.conf and my init script.

My supervisord.conf file had the following settings:

```
pidfile=/tmp/supervisord.pid
```

But my init script at `/etc/init.d/supervisord` had the following setting:

```
NAME=supervisord
PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
```

So I just changed the setting in supervisord.conf to match what was in my init script.

Also, I added `stopsignal=KILL` to the program config in my supervisord config file (supervisord.conf).

Thanks to Minaz for the direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I always include the stopsignal config option for my supervisor config files. This allows the gearman process to be killed when a stop is requested. Try this:

```
[program:gearman] 
command=/usr/bin/php php_gearman_worker.php
numprocs=1 
directory=/root/sandbox
stdout_logfile=/root/sandbox/supervisord.log 
environment=GEARMAN_USER=gearman 
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=gearman
stopsignal=KILL
```

Comment: I updated the supervisord.conf file and added the `stopsignal=KILL` but it doesn't kill the processes when I stop supervisord, not sure why

Comment: just curious, do you need to restart supervisord frequently?

Comment: No, I'm just testing the system out to make sure everything is working as it should. It does the same thing on a stop and start, not just a restart. I've found what the issue was though, I'm posting the info in an edit of the question.

Comment: Processes don't stop when supervisord quits. This is so you can upgrade supervisord and still keep your long running processes running